# Can we convert a Linux distribution to another by simply copying the set of applications?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, distribution-choice, distributions, software-distribution

If Linux distributions differ by the set of applications, then is it possible to convert one Linux distribution to another by simply copying the apps of that distribution to the target distribution?

For example, if I will copy the apps of Ubuntu and paste it to Kali, would that make Kali become Ubuntu, or vice versa, etc., etc.?

Comment: No it will not work especially when talking about different Linux families (redhat/debian/etc). This is because apart from packages, Linux distributions also have more or less different configurations of the packages. And in some cases different software is used (example gnome vs kde).

Comment: What do you mean by copying packages? All installed software? Copy the entire drive?

Comment: @terdon yes. I mean if for example I will copy all Ubuntu apps to another distro, would that distro be essentially Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm afraid you're not answering the question. copying apps is not the same as copying packages and both are different from copying the entire contents of the disk. What _exactly_ are you thinking of copying. Would you copy the kernel too? Kernel modules? Configuration files? User setup files like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`? Would you just copy the packages and not the contents (copy the dpkg files), and then install the packages on the new machine? You need to be very specific in order to get a specific answer here because otherwise it is a philosophical question.

Comment: @terdon not the kernel of course. I mean only those applications that are meant for one distro, which are not meant for another distro.

Comment: @Noob_Guy yes, again, what does that mean? Would you copy the packages and install on the new distro? Would you copy the executable files? Would you also copy the libraries used? How about configuration files? Would you delete the corresponding ones from the new distro? Would you copy kernel modules? There is no such thing as "applications that are meant for one distro, which are not meant for another distro".

Comment: @terdon copy the executable files

Comment: OK I'm sorry but I really don't want to do this any more. I have asked you several questions, you keep on only answering one of them. If you want to get an answer, [edit] your question and make it more specific. Look at the questions I have asked, and make the imaginary scenario you are presenting specific enough to be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, that is *not* possible. The closest thing you have is [Bedrock Linux](https://bedrocklinux.org/), which allows you to sort of mix-and-match. It is clear that you are inexperienced as a Linux user (not saying that I am a master in any way), so Bedrock would not be recommended for you to use.

The main reason for this is package managers: "every" Linux distribution uses their own package manager. For example, the Red Hat-based distros (Fedora, RHEL, CentOS) use `yum` and `dnf`, Debian-based (many; a good example would be Ubuntu) use `apt`, and so on.

To simple it down: applications depend on libraries. These applications use libraries to, for example, display buttons. Instead of writing the code into the application to include buttons, they use functions provided from libraries. This means that the applications depend on these libraries - some which depend on other libraries again - and applications are very sensitive to changes in libraries; a small change in a lib may mess up the whole application.

They are trying to solve this by shipping applications with libraries/dependencies baked in. Flatpaks and Snaps would be examples of this, where applications work across distributions. This way, you don't need to use Fedora to use applications that originally only exist on Fedora to work on e.g. Ubuntu, or vice-versa.

**NB:** everything I've explained above is *how I've understood it*. If I am wrong, I'd be more than happy to learn from more experienced users.

---

That being said, are you asking because you want to use a specific set of applications on Ubuntu or Kali? It is somewhat possible to do this: depending on the application, you may use Snap or Flatpak, if they exist in their repos. If you need applications which are not in the Snap or Flatpak repos, you could use tools like `podman` or `distrobox` (the latter being easier to use if you're "green" to containers), which allow you to create containers that "mimic" a specific distro. That way, you can use the official repos to pull in packages and dependencies from the distro you are "mimicking".

Comment: I'm asking this to further understand the differences between distros. Thanks for answering.